# Is there a way to password protect a windows application on Windows 7 without changing the exe?

Tags: windows-7, password-protection

I want to password-protect a few applications (not just files/folders) on Windows 7, such that, there is no change to the protected application's .exe file itself.

Since the .exe files can't be changed, "[Empathy](http://migeel.sk/projects/empathy/)" and "[Protect Exe](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Lockdown/Protect-EXE.shtml)" can't be used as they change the .exe file.

I tried using [WinGuard Pro](http://www.winguardpro.com/) and [LockThis!](http://www.duriosoft.com/products/lockthis.html) also but they don't work for Microsoft Outlook and some other apps (that I need).

Is it possible at all? Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to password protect them? (If it is to only allow a limited subset of users to run them, then there are other ways.)

Comment: What sort of access do the users normally have on the system?  Are they in the Administrators group?

Answer (score 1):

A computer administrator can use user account to set up permissions for access to individual applications, rather than trying to password the executable files.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to protect the files from modification, not execution.

Comment: Iszi is correct, hence *“such that, there is no change to the protected application's .exe file itself.”* Of course write-access can be set as well, so that should do the trick.

Comment: Not going to argue over semantics.